# update sum function from another table in vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access

At vba aceess, I have 2 tables, "payment" table and "DetailToEvent" table. the 2 tables join together with EventID. at the "DetailToEvent" table I have lots of item for the same EventID. I would like to summerize all the costs for the eventID and update the payment table with the total value.I thought of some like:

```
    UPDATE DetailToEvent LEFT JOIN Payment ON DetailToEvent.EventID = Payment.EventID SET Payment.TotalPayment = [DetailToEvent].[TotalPrice]
WHERE (((DetailToEvent.EventID)=20));
```

but the problem is I can't add the sum and group by.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with one parameterized query to fit your example.
I haven't tested my logic or SQL so there's probably a tweak or two to be made
And I'm guessing you can do a join with an Update query - but better check that out too

Hopefully this is a start

```
UPDATE Payment
SET Payment.TotalPayment = Totals.Total
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Payment.EventID, SUM([DetailToEvent].[TotalPrice]) AS Total
    FROM DetailToEvent
    INNER JOIN Payment
    ON DetailToEvent.EventID = Payment.EventID
    GROUP BY Payment.EventID) AS Totals
ON Payment.EventID = Totals.EventID
WHERE Payment.EventID = [What Event ID]
```